# Vue/Webpack/Typescript - How to use jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I want to use the jQuery Plugin chosen in my vue.js/Webpack with TypeScript application.

I read that it it's best to wrap the plugin in a custom Vue component.

I installed the NPM packages:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
npm install chosen-js --save
npm install @types/chosen-js --save
```

My component:

```
<template>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Test1</option>
        <option value="2">Test2</option>
    </select>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
    import $ from 'jquery';    
    import 'chosen-js';

    @Component
    export default class ChosenSelect extends Vue{
        @Prop()options!:string;
        @Prop()value!:string;

        mounted() {
            let vm = this;
            let el = $(vm.$el);
            console.log(el);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Without **import 'chosen-js'** jQuery is working - when I'm using the component in another component I get a console output.

With **import 'chosen-js'** I only get `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` from the chosen library.

What is the right way to import both - jQuery and chosen-js and use it in a vue Typescript component.

Comment: Why would you want to use jQuery alongside Vue.js? The whole point of a framework like Vue.js is to avoid direct DOM manipulations...

Comment: Because there exist some really good and functional jQuery plugins without a vue.js implementation in the same quality. Why "throw away" everything that worked for years? ;-)

Comment: Because you have components such as sliders, image galleries and menu/navigation systems that are written in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

first, install jquery

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

then in any of your component add this.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

check if jquery works by doing something like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

export default class Home extends Vue {
  created () {
    this.test()
  }

  test () {
    console.log($('body'))  // It's work
  }
}
```

Sometimes you need to wait for the dom to be loaded in order to do your jquery things.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div id="test">wijfwoe</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as $ from 'jquery';
export default class Home extends Vue {
  created () {
  }

  mounted () {
        let a = $('#test')[0];
        console.log(a.textContent);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the main.ts file and it will be available inside the components.

```
declare global {
    interface Window { $: any; }
}
window.$ = require('jquery')
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using a Vue-specific select plugin, rather than having to rely on a jQuery-based one that somewhat defeats the purpose of using something like Vue in terms of DOM manipulations. Most of these already bring in their own components, so there's no need to create a wrapper.

There's a great list of Vue resources maintained here, not just for plugins: [awesome-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#select)

Comment: There is a vue plugin (vue-select) trying to recreate the functionality of chosen-js/select2 but it's not as good as the mentioned jQuery libraries and I don't want to waste hours modifying it if it's possible to just drop in the jQuery plugin... for now - even if it's manipulating the DOM directly
.